# Store "Documents and Settings" on a different drive. Windows 2003 Terminal Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, profile

The situation is this. I have 2 terminal servers in an estate with lots and lots of servers.
The TS's can be used by anyone and will primarily be used for remote working (via a VPN solution). The users who will use the TS will also be using other desktop machines, and appropriate group policies for desktop builds etc are already in place.

What I need to do is move the c:\documents and settings folder to the D:\ drive for all users.

For various reasons, the profiles need to be local to the machine and a D: drive with suitable space has been created.

I have setup some test users with a Terminal Servers Profile setup within AD with the following settings:

Profile Path: d:\profile\%username%

Terminal Services Home Folder | Local Path: d:\profiles\%username%

With this done on the d: drive a profile folder with the username will be created, but only a "Windows" fodler will be created in there. THe normal documents and settings stuff still appears in the C Drive.

How do I stop this and point all at D:\ drive?

For info, I have started with fresh accounts.

Comment: The Profile Path is for the Roaming Profile, not the Local one. The Home Folder is simply the default location for newly created Documents (AD will also create a the folder automatically if it's a network location).

Answer (score 4):

Use group policy folders redirection to redirect My documents to any other location:

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=216463

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc737434%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: +1, This will redirect all new profiles to the new location. You can also move existing profile to the new location then edit the registry entry so Windows knows where to find them: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\{SID}\ProFileImagePath`

Comment: I only want to redirect stuff if they are on the terminal server, not if they are on thei rnormal workstations.....does this do that?

Comment: Create own OU for your terminal server users and assign policy object with folders redirection to it.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the problem. I have 2/3 terminal servers which the users will loginto depending on load / role etc and they will need to have locally stored profiles on each, just on different drives....

Comment: The policy is applied to the machine not the user.

Comment: 2JamesRyan: Orly? I can use security filtering to apply GPO to specified group or manage to apply only Computer/User settings of this GPO.So...


2Kip: You can configure own GPO with specific folders redirection for each TS if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Group Policy

User Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Folder Redirection
Folders 
for the personal folders that can be redirected will be displayed.